# Access to the path 'sharable drive' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a shared folder.  I get

> Access to the path 'sharable folder path' is denied.

Now here is the thing-- in an app i made for testing purposes, i can access that folder which is  stored on a server.
when i include that code into an existing app where it will be living i get that error.

I used hard coded password/username in both just for testing

how can i have it work for my testing app but for an app that already exists it doesnt work.

```cs
string test = "\\\\theserver";
                  
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        
CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
theNetCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
string[] theFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(test + "\\Sharable");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you may not be able to access the folder could be due to folder permissions. You may need to grant the "**Everyone**" permission or you may need to run the program as an administrator. When you give the "**Everyone**" permission, I guess your program will be able to access that folder.

Comment: thanks but that is not an option so we will be creating another folder with specific permissions